# Вывести два ближайшие часы к полудню C++

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, строки, классы

Не понимаю как можно решать эту задачу, помогите пожалуйста разобраться...

нужно вывести два ближайшие часы(время) к полудню из введенных часов

Примеры

Входные данные

5

10 58

13 0

12 0

11 59

20 6

Результат работы

11 59

12 0

Входные данные

3

10 25

9 10

14 25

Результат работы

10 25

14 25

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
class Time{
    public:
    int hours;
    int minutes;
};
 
int main() {
  unsigned int N;
  cin >> N;
  Time* t = new Time[N];
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    cin >> t[i].hours >> t[i].minutes;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто отсортировать с особым критерием - считая число тем меньшим, чем оно ближе к 12:00. Проще бы хранить в минутах, но если дописывать к вашей программе, то вот что у меня получилось.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Time {
    public:
        int hours;
        int minutes;
    };

int main() {
    unsigned int N;
    cin >> N;
    Time* t = new Time[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cin >> t[i].hours >> t[i].minutes;

    partial_sort(t, t + 2, t + N,
    [](auto a, auto b) {
        return abs(60 * (a.hours - 12) + a.minutes) <
               abs(60 * (b.hours - 12) + b.minutes);
        });
    cout << t[0].hours << " " << t[0].minutes << endl;
    cout << t[1].hours << " " << t[1].minutes << endl;
    }
```

Можно совсем просто - запомнить первые два значения, а потом каждое новое сравнивать с имеющимися и если оно ближе - выполнять замену самого удаленного от 12 из двух на новое. Так даже массив не нужен.